# тип данных Char sql

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, вопрос такого рода, в документации написано, что при записи в поле с типом данных CHAR(длинна), поле дополняется после текста пробелами, но при извлечение пробелы удаляются. Я работаю с базой sql на C# и как-то эти пробелы не удаляются, в чём проблема? (работаю с базой через EF)

Comment: *в документации написано* Пожалуйста, сошлитесь на конкретную фразу конкретной страницы документации на конкретный программный продукт.

Comment: @Akina, «http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/CHAR.html»

Comment: Вы используете 4-ю версию MySQL? точно? А если нет - то обратитесь к документации по СВОЕЙ версии. И особенно внимательно рассмотрите самый первый пример статьи.